# Use of unresolved identifier 'UIMutableUserNotificationAction'

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I have a separate Singleton class containing LocalNotification registration and Action setup code. I am getting

```
Use of unresolved identifier error
```

Added all classes to XCTest target as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the `UIKit` framework

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mutNotification = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        mutNotification.identifier = "Y"
    }
}
```